Firebase:Internal Error When requesting OTP
so im using firebase auth and in that im using phone provider, from yesterday firebase is saying
"An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information."
during requesting OTP.
I have checked that my phone provider is turned on and one more thing its working very fine for test numbers.
the logs that im getting is like this
flutter: exeption.credential: null
flutter: exeption.tenantId: null
flutter: exeption.phoneNumber: null
flutter: exeption.plugin: firebase_auth
flutter: exeption.code: internal-error
flutter: exeption.message: An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.
flutter: exeption.stackTrace: null


this is the code snippet im using

await _firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: updatedMobileNumber,
        verificationCompleted: (authCredential) {
          print("authCredential.smsCode: ${authCredential.smsCode}");
          // if (!otpAutoFill.isCompleted) {
          //   otpAutoFill.complete(authCredential.smsCode);
          // }
        },
        verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException exeption) {
          print("exeption.credential: ${exeption.credential}");
          print("exeption.tenantId: ${exeption.tenantId}");
          print("exeption.phoneNumber: ${exeption.phoneNumber}");
          print("exeption.plugin: ${exeption.plugin}");
          print("exeption.code: ${exeption.code}");
          print("exeption.message: ${exeption.message}");
          print("exeption.stackTrace: ${exeption.stackTrace}");

          _verifyPhoneException = exeption;
          if (!completer!.isCompleted) completer!.complete(false);
        },
        codeSent: (verificationCode, [code]) {
          _verificationCode = verificationCode;
          if (!completer!.isCompleted) completer!.complete(true);
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationCode) {
          _verificationCode = verificationCode;
          if (!completer!.isCompleted) completer!.complete(true);
        },
);

I'm not able to understand what should i do here???

The following steps resolved the issue:

Update Flutter to the latest version by running: flutter upgrade
Use the latest version : firebase_auth: ^5.3.1

